# Pandas python what to solve in IndexError

Tags: python, pandas

I receive the following error when I try to count occurences of each element in `ListA` from `ListB`.

```html
ListA = [*range(0,10000000, 1)]
ListB = [5,4,778,577,369,1147, 7851387,115547,...]

count_arr = np.bincount(ListB)
Number_of_counts = [count_arr[x] for x in ListA]
```

I get the following error with which I do not know what is wrong since `ListA` is just a range of numbers.

```html
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-2f121c135a65> in <module>
      1 count_arr = np.bincount(ListA)
----> 2 Number_of_counts = [count_arr[x] for x in ListB]

<ipython-input-18-2f121c135a65> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 count_arr = np.bincount(ListB)
----> 2 Number_of_counts = [count_arr[x] for x in ListA]

IndexError: index 1715766 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1715766
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ListA's` length is bigger than `count_arr`'s length. Therefore, when you loop through `count_arr` using `ListA`'s indexes, you get and error. Their length should be the same